# $S$ subring of $R$ implies $\mathrm{rank}_R M\leq \mathrm{rank}_S M$?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

This is a question that I've posted [in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3521468/s-subring-of-r-implies-mathrmrank-r-m-leq-mathrmrank-s-m) but I've got no answers.

The statement is as follows:

Let $R$ be a ring with identity, and $S$ be a subring with $1_S=1_R$. Let $M$ be a free unitary $R$-module such that there exists $\mathrm{rank}_R M$ (i.e. every $R$-basis of $M$ has the same cardinality).

Is it true that $\mathrm{rank}_S M$ exists?

And, in the case that $\mathrm{rank}_S M$ exists, is it true (as in vector spaces) that $\mathrm{rank}_R M\leq \mathrm{rank}_S M$?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: How are you defining rank of a general module? For finitely generated free modules, the condition you describe is known as IBN (invariant basis number), that is, $R^n $ isomorphic to $R^m$ implies $m = n$, and this property is obviously preserved by taking unital subrings.

Comment: If any two R-bases for M have the same cardinality, then the rank_R of M is the number of the elements of any R-basis

Comment: First question: Probably no, consider $M=R$.

Comment: A more natural question would be: Assume that $\mathrm{rank}_R(M)$ and $\mathrm{rank}_S(R)$ exist. Does  $\mathrm{rank}_S(M)$ exist and do we have $$\mathrm{rank}_S(M) = \mathrm{rank}_S(R) \cdot \mathrm{rank}_R(M)?$$I think this equation is quite straight forward once we know that $\mathrm{rank}_S(M)$ exists (i.e. all $S$-bases of $M$ have the same cardinality).